# Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "npipe": invalid mount path: '\\.\pipe\docker_engine' mount path must be absolute

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I don't have a docker desktop installed. Instead, I have installed the docker engine i.e. I have required command files in a specific folder. This is given in the %PATH% environment variable. I want to run the docker containers without Docker Desktop.

[image]

When the below command is run.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

It gives the following error.

[image]

> Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "npipe":
> invalid mount path: '\.\pipe\docker_engine' mount path must be
> absolute

Following is the docker-compose.yml snippet and is not the complete code.

```
services:
  traefik:
    isolation: ${TRAEFIK_ISOLATION}
    image: ${TRAEFIK_IMAGE}
    command:
      - "--ping"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.file.directory=C:/etc/traefik/config/dynamic"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8079:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        type: npipe
      - ./traefik:C:/etc/traefik
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_healthy
      cd:
        condition: service_healthy
      cm:
        condition: service_healthy
```

There seems something wrong with the following lines in the above snippet.

```
"--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"

    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        type: npipe
```

Any idea what needs to be changed here? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use the preferred format, as in `//./pipe/docker_engine`